# HTML Select output from jQuery function is NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to define a variable with the selected option from an HTML `<select>` tag. Here is the small bit of HTML:

```
function addmatch(){
       var heroadd = $('#select_hero').val();
       var winlossadd = $('#winloss option:selected').val();
       var gamemodeadd = $('#gamemode option:selected').val();
       var mmradd = $('#input_mmr').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"php/InsertMatch.php",
        data: {hero: heroadd, winloss: + winlossadd, gamemode: + gamemodeadd, mmr: + mmradd}})
        .done(function() {
            alert("New match has been added");
        });
}
```

The problem appears to be when I send the data to ajax. Whilst the winlossadd contains "win" for example, when sending the data it comes out as NaN in the database.

Comment: What happens if you `console.log($('#winloss option:selected'));`? Is there anything output?

Comment: That works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kh32D/. The only way you could get NaN is if you are trying to convert the value to a number.

Comment: The correct way to get the value of a `<select>` element is to call `.val()` on the `<select>` element: `$('#winloss').val()`. In this case, however, that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: And where is your jQuery statement there? I think you need to put your ideas in order before asking here.

Comment: @Adripanico Sorry I tried to isolate to where I thought the problem was but I was incorrect. I rashly posted here and that is my fault. updating post again now

Comment: @adripanico updated the question now to reflect the actual state of the problem. I apologise again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
data: {hero: heroadd, winloss: + winlossadd, gamemode: + gamemodeadd, mmr: + mmradd}})
```

Putting `+` before a variable attempts to convert that variable to a number. You can just drop the `+`:

```
data: {hero: heroadd, winloss: winlossadd, gamemode: gamemodeadd, mmr: mmradd}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code show work with no issue.

**HTML**

```
<select id="winloss">
    <option value="Win">Win</option>
    <option value="Loss">Loss</option>
</select>
<button id="showSelected">Show Selected</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#showSelected').click( function () {
        alert( $('#winloss option:selected').val() );
    });
});
```

check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5JUp/)